# GAE Returning 404 after period of no traffic

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm new to GAE and python (also my first post on Stack Overflow). I have a basic site up on GAE. I'm using Python 2.7. There is little traffic to it, since I am the only one accessing it at this point.

The problem is that whenever I hit the main url after a period of inactivity (longer then 10-15 minutes), I get a 404 from my ISP (Rogers). After about 15 seconds, if I retry the main url, the page loads.

I thought it might have been because the instances had to spin up. So I upgraded have a paid GAE account, and set it up so that there is a minimum of one instance running at all times. The GAE dashboard shows at lease one instance running for the past day. But the problem persists.

Here is my app.yaml

```
application: resumesite
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
  - url: /static
    static_dir: static

  - url: /.*
    script: main.app

inbound_services:
  - warmup

libraries:
  - name: jinja2
    version: latest
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: "get a 404 from my ISP (Rogers)" -- that indicates that either you aren't explaining the failure correctly, or something totally unrelated to GAE is where the problem lies.

Comment: What happens if you check the url using a third party E.g. [tools.pingdom.com](http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/)? If you don't see the 404 error then the error is most likely coming from your ISP.

Comment: Thanks Kyle. It does appear to be working with pingdom.

Comment: What do the logs show? Where's the code for the handler that handles the URL you're testing?

Comment: It usually takes less than a second for a new instance to warm up (my app takes ~250ms) so unless there is something horribly wrong with the code then it isn't that. Could you try disabling warmup requests (they are designed to minimize latency on the first request to an instance however it is *possible* that something erroneous is going on there).And as Nick says - every response from your app will be logged so that is a good place to look, you will also be able to see warmup requests (look at how long they take, if it is more than 300ms then something isn't right).

Comment: I had the same issue. Mine was due to the fact that redirects to register handlers where not aborting the root request. Idk if this helps... But if you can explain your logic behind your root page request it might help.